# ZF2 form element description

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2, zend-form-element

in ZF1 form and form elements had a `setDescription` method that was outputted as `<p>description here</p>` in view ....
ZF2 seems that doesn't have this method 
so my question is how can i add description to form elements ?

this is my view :

```
<div>
    <?
    $form = $this->form;
    $form->prepare();
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);

    foreach ($form->getElements() as $el) {
        ?>
        <div class="form_element">
            <?=$this->formRow($el);?>
        </div>
        <?
    }
    echo $this->partial('system/form/buttons_form_part.phtml', array('form' => $form));
    echo $this->form()->closeTag();
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using ZF 2.1.5, one solution might be `setOptions()`.

In the form definiton:

```
$file = new Element\File('file');
$file->setLabel('Photo (.jpg, .gif, .png)');
$file->setOptions(array('description' => 'test description'));
…
```

When rendering the form element:

```
$element = $form->get(…);    
var_dump($element->getOptions());
```

Will give you access to:

```
array(1) { ["description"]=> string(16) "test description" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a label for an Element you can use the `setLabel` method when you create the form (in Controller).

```
$name = new Element('name');
$name->setLabel('Your name');
```

Or if you use an array to create your form elements use this:

```
array(
        'spec' => array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Your name',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text'
            ),
        )
    ),
```

Here is a link:

[enter link description here](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html)