# zf2 form collection don't show element description

Tags: forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2, formcollection

When the collection element is rendered , description element does not appear.
ZF2 seems to ignore the description option in the form collection.

**Form**

```
$this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
        'name' => 'value',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Please choose value',
            'count' => 1,
            'should_create_template' => true,
            'target_element' => new ValueFieldset($objectManager)
        )
    ));
```

**Form Fieldset:** ValueFieldset

```
$this->add(array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Values',
                    'label_attributes' => array(
                        'class' => 'form-label'
                    ),
                    'description' => '<a href="#" class="remove-value">X</a>', 
                    'multiple' => true,
                  ),

            )
    );
```

View

```
echo $this->formCollection($values);
```

Comment: Try it with single text, so no html. Maybe that's the problem. but not sure, never used description. I use to render one field at the time and then I add my custom description at the view level.

Comment: [ZF2 doesn't have a 'description' method as ZF1 did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378957/zf2-form-element-description); You will need to manually render the description, by fetching the element options (i.e `$element->getOptions()`) from within the view.